# Make absolute child div overflow out of its scrollable relative root parent in CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to let child div (with green color) out of its root parent (with red color), it's work when I remove `overflow-y:scroll` attribute from the root parent div, but I need the parent root to be scrollable.

CSS Code :

```css
    .root-parent{
      font-size:20px;
      overflow-y:scroll;
      background-color:red;
      height:100px;
      width:100%;
    }
    .parent{
      width:50%;
      background-color:blue;
      height:50px;
      position:relative;
    }
    .child{
      width:50%;
      height:200px;
      background-color:green;
      position:absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div class="root-parent">
      <div>1</div>
      <div class="parent">
         <div class="child">
           <div>2</div>
           <div>2</div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

this is the [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KGgLKJ) to see how it looks like ^^

Comment: you need to decide, you want to scroll the overflow or you want the overflow to be visible?.. you cannot have both

Comment: yes the overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `top` rule to the `child` class and remove the `position: relative` from the blue div, then it will be position above the red div.

position absolute refers to the first ancestor with position relative.

**UPDATE**

If you want to make the red div scrollable and also overflow the green div it cannot be done with CSS alone.  You can do it with JS. Calculate the top location of your blue element and set it as top rule to the green element

[Here's an example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YJGbve)

Comment: thank's for your answer but i think is not a good practice because im not sure that the content height value in the the top of the child is 100px.

Comment: You need to place it somewhere, set the pixels/percentage as you need, I'm just guiding you how to do it. You also didn't say exactly where you want to plce it, so I gave an example with 100px

Comment: thank's, but i think that you misunderstand me, the begin of the green div must be inside the blue div but it's end must be out of the red div

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: thank's i think that i can't do it without JavaScript